# Book about two feuding brothers

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember one brother was blonde and the other was dark haired. They got transported to a different world or place Somehow and the blonde one started hunting down his brother later. The dark haired one was a musician. Started reading it about 8 years ago

Comment: Can you give any more detail?  This is a little too vague.

Answer (score 5):

I just found it. It was *Curse of the Mistwraith*, first in the Wars of Light and Shadow series by Janny Wurst.

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_the_Mistwraith) summary:

> Born on a splinter world, Lysaer and Arithon are half-brothers raised
>   apart in enmity. Cast through a Worldsend Gate, they arrive in Athera,
>   the ancient world of their ancestors cloaked in the fog of the
>   malicious Mistwraith. Found by the Fellowship of Seven and urged to
>   fulfill a prophecy which will free Athera from the Mistwraith and
>   allow the clans of the Old Bloodlines to rule again.

and the cover image there shows the two brothers:

[image: cover of "Curse of the Mistwraith"]